# Is there a similar tool like Curl but is already included in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, rhel, curl

I'm not sure if there is a similar command/utility which comes along with Linux distro CentOs, Ubuntu and RedHat without installing Curl.

Basically I'd like to do a command like below

```
curl -H https://website.com/api?...
```

...but doesn't want to install any tool.

Comment: Do-able using Python.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331430/emulating-a-curl-command-with-python  Or wget.

Comment: I'm not interested in mixing both Python and native Bash shell in one script. With Wget you still need to install

Comment: Is "curl" not installed in the Minimal Install package set for Ubuntu? I know `curl` is part of the @core environment group on RHEL/CentOS 7, so it should be installed by default, unless you have removed it for some reason.

Comment: @0xSheepdog would you have a link to indicate Curl is part of minimal install packet set? I don't see it being present here https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-minimal

Comment: I don't know about Ubuntu, thus why I asked if it was part of the minimal set. It **_is_** part of the minimal set of packages for RHEL and CentOS.

Comment: How "similar" to curl do you need? You demonstrate `-H` which appears to be `Extra header to include in the request when sending HTTP to a server`; what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @JeffSchaller my command is just to query API to retrieve an information with Curl. I'd like to know if I could make the similar function without installing Curl or Wget.

Comment: Looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951459/309308

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `openssl` for that (if you need https) or `nc` and parse output by yourself. But are you sure that it's required? Even if you are not sure about curl already installed, python still is good choise with option to use urllib. And here is example of `openssl` usage:

```
printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" | openssl s_client -connect reklamavip.ru:443 -crlf -ign_eof -quiet -verify_return_error 2>/dev/null
```